# How to configure xampp/wamp server to allow android phone to access it?

Tags: php, android, xampp, wamp

I followed this tutorial here [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFGNtINmEBQ)

The thing is it worked on the emulator. Which mean when I pressed the sign/register button data was stored and login. But it doesn't work on my actual device. :( I tried to follow tutorial on how to set up for example changing the http conf file. But all didn't work.

This is my logcat output when I pressed the login/register button,

```
01-01 23:49:41.551    3359-3359/my.mysql_php_register_login D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-01 23:49:41.851    3359-3428/my.mysql_php_register_login I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
01-01 23:49:41.861    3359-3428/my.mysql_php_register_login I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

Comment: Can you access the api url from your phone? Both of them need to be on same network or the `IP` of your php file must be a public.

Comment: Take your browser and type it.

Comment: erm sorry I don't quite understand. What do I type?

Comment: You are calling a url right? Something like `http://10.0.2.2/path/login.php`.

Comment: http://192.168.1.213:8080/data/user_control.php I typed this. it said webpage not avaibale. 192.168 is my pc ip address

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99536/discussion-between-k-neeraj-lal-and-spotty).

Comment: @KNeerajLal Firewall problem. Solved it. :)